# PH7 and PHP classes

Tags: php, c++

I'm looking into [PH7](http://ph7.symisc.net/) for possibly adding scripting to my game engine. I'm looking for an example on loading a PHP class defined in a PHP file from and creating an instance of it and calling it's methods from a C++ program. The only examples I can find are where the PHP file is just commands instead of class definitions.

Anyone know how this is done?